# How to aggregate map columns after groupBy?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to union two dataframes and combine the columns by keys. The two datafrmaes have the same schema, for example:

```
root
|-- id: String (nullable = true)
|-- cMap: map (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string
|    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I want to group by "id" and aggregate the "cMap" together to deduplicate.
I tried the code:

```
val df = df_a.unionAll(df_b).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("cMap") as "cMap").
rdd.map(x => {
    var map = Map[String,String]()
    x.getAs[Seq[Map[String,String]]]("cMap").foreach( y => 
        y.foreach( tuple =>
        {
            val key = tuple._1
            val value = tuple._2
            if(!map.contains(key))//deduplicate
                map += (key -> value)
        }))

    Row(x.getAs[String]("id"),map)
    })
```

But it seems collect_list cannnot be used to map structure:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No handler for Hive udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList because: Only primitive type arguments are accepted but map<string,string> was passed as parameter 1..;
```

Is there other solution for the problem?

Comment: Can you upgrade to 2.x? Hive isn't required for aggregate functions in 2.x

Comment: your mistake is that you are using `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList` but you have to use is `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list` and it should work then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `explode` function on the map columns first to *destructure* maps into key and value columns, `union` the result datasets followed by `distinct` to de-duplicate and only then `groupBy` with some custom Scala coding to aggregate the maps.

Stop talking and let's do some coding then...

Given the datasets:

```
scala> a.show(false)
+---+-----------------------+
|id |cMap                   |
+---+-----------------------+
|one|Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)|
+---+-----------------------+

scala> a.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cMap: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

scala> b.show(false)
+---+-------------+
|id |cMap         |
+---+-------------+
|one|Map(1 -> one)|
+---+-------------+

scala> b.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cMap: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

You should first use [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function on the map columns.

> **explode(e: Column): Column** Creates a new row for each element in the given array or map column.

```
val a_keyValues = a.select('*, explode($"cMap"))
scala> a_keyValues.show(false)
+---+-----------------------+---+-----+
|id |cMap                   |key|value|
+---+-----------------------+---+-----+
|one|Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)|1  |one  |
|one|Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)|2  |two  |
+---+-----------------------+---+-----+

val b_keyValues = b.select('*, explode($"cMap"))
```

With the following you have distinct key-value pairs which is exactly deduplication you asked for.

```
val distinctKeyValues = a_keyValues.
  union(b_keyValues).
  select("id", "key", "value").
  distinct // <-- deduplicate
scala> distinctKeyValues.show(false)
+---+---+-----+
|id |key|value|
+---+---+-----+
|one|1  |one  |
|one|2  |two  |
+---+---+-----+
```

Time for `groupBy` and create the final map column.

```
val result = distinctKeyValues.
  withColumn("map", map($"key", $"value")).
  groupBy("id").
  agg(collect_list("map")).
  as[(String, Seq[Map[String, String]])]. // <-- leave Rows for typed pairs
  map { case (id, list) => (id, list.reduce(_ ++ _)) }. // <-- collect all entries under one map
  toDF("id", "cMap") // <-- give the columns their names
scala> result.show(truncate = false)
+---+-----------------------+
|id |cMap                   |
+---+-----------------------+
|one|Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)|
+---+-----------------------+
```

---

Please note that as of Spark 2.0.0 [unionAll](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@unionAll(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) has been deprecated and `union` is the proper union operator:

> (Since version 2.0.0) use union()

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I found after applying select('*, explode($"xxx")), the amount of records decrease a lot, i guess it is because of the null or empty Map value. But I am not sure.  As I have another columns in my real projects, I seperate the columns into string type ones and map type one, aggregate seperately and join together. By the way, what is the syntax for '\* . Thanks.

Comment: _"By the way, what is the syntax for '*"_ <-- it's another version of `$"*"`

Comment: This is phenomenal. Spark devs should work to implement a `collect_map()` sql function with a couple of different signatures.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Is this works only for particular spark version ? Cuz I followed your approach but getting exception - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750717/spark-java-lang-classcastexception-cannot-assign-instance-of-scala-collection

Answer (score 8):

Since Spark 3.0, you can:

- transform your map to an array of map entries with `map_entries`
- collect those arrays by your id using `collect_set`
- flatten the collected array of arrays using `flatten`
- then rebuild the map from flattened array using `map_from_entries`

See following code snippet where `input` is your input dataframe:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_set, flatten, map_entries, map_from_entries}

input
  .withColumn("cMap", map_entries(col("cMap")))
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(map_from_entries(flatten(collect_set("cMap"))).as("cMap"))
```

#### Example

Given the following dataframe input:

```
+---+--------------------+
|id |cMap                |
+---+--------------------+
|1  |[k1 -> v1]          |
|1  |[k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3]|
|2  |[k4 -> v4]          |
|2  |[]                  |
|3  |[k6 -> v6, k7 -> v7]|
+---+--------------------+
```

The code snippet above returns the following dataframe:

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |cMap                          |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |[k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3]|
|3  |[k6 -> v6, k7 -> v7]          |
|2  |[k4 -> v4]                    |
+---+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Shankar. Your codes seems to be flawless.

The only mistake I assume you are doing is that you are importing wrong library.

You had to import

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
```

But I guess you are importing

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList
```

I hope I am guessing it right.